# Returning undefined while calling same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code

```
function secondval_prompt(firstval) {
  var secondval = prompt("should be greater than 1st value");
  if((secondval > firstval) && (secondval != "") && (!isNaN(secondval))) {
    return secondval;
  } else {
    secondval_prompt(firstval);
  }
}

var firstvalue = prompt("Enter 1st value");
var secondvalue = secondval_prompt(firstvalue);
alert(secondvalue);
```

If I gave the `second value` greater that `first value` on first time its returning the `second value` correctly.Once I gave the `second value` as wrong (less than `first value`) on first time and gave the correct value(greater than `first value`) on second time it return `undefined`...

Why its returning `undefined` on `second` attempt..

Demo link : http://jsbin.com/balufete/1/edit?js,output

Please try like this

**First**

Give first value as `100` &
Give Second value as `101`
It will return `101`

**Second**

Give first value as `100` &
Give Second value as `10` &
Again give Second value as `101`
It will return `undefined`

Comment: Your function seem to be missing a return statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `return` the value from the recursive function as well.

```
return secondval_prompt(firstval);
```

Note that you are currently doing a comparison on the *text* values entered in the prompt. `"5"` will be considered higher than `"10"` due to their respective alphabetical order. You may want to `parseInt` the two inputs:

```
if(parseInt(secondval, 10) > parseInt(firstval, 10))
```

You should also apply `firstval` the same validity tests that you're currently applying to  `secondval`. At the moment, your code will accept non-number values for `firstval`.